# issue with html li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Is it possible to add an attribute to html list elements (li)?

I need to have another attribute, I already used both value and html attributes.

Is there a way to fix it?

Maybe with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use data attributes from HTML5

```
<li data-val="yourvalue" />
```

To access it you just do this

```
$('li').attr('data-val') ;  OR $('li').data('val') ;
```

Your can specify any name to your attribute..

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use HTML5 [`data-*` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) to add arbitrary data to any element:

```
<li data-something="randomvalue">
```

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery, you can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get the value of a `data-*` attribute. Without jQuery, the best way is to use the usual [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute) method.

Comment: like $('li').data("randomvalue");

Answer (score 0):

Try  **.append** in jquery if u want to add attribute **dynamically**

Comment: `.append()` is used to append *elements* to the DOM. It won't help you add an *attribute* to an existing element.